# What are different ways to roast Bell Peppers?

Tags: roasting, bell-peppers

I was wondering if anyone had any tips for roasting bell peppers so that they get a nice blacked skin.  I live in an apartment, and if I were to put the peppers directly on the burners, it would not go over too well.  (I did start to do that, but when it started to heat, the pepper started to stick to the burner.)  I tried to use my George Foreman grill, but wasn't able to get the char on the skin that I was looking for in order to take the skin off.  (Note: the flavor did turn out well for what I was making, but I know it would be even better if they were charred.)

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: However you end up roasting it, if you want the skin off, put the peppers in a zip-top bag as soon as you remove them from the heat. Seal the bag and leave them for a few minutes, and the skin will loosen and slide right off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming by your wording, you don't have a bbq on a balcony. Another alternative to the broiler, is a blow torch to get the nice charing. :-)

http://www.open2.net/everwonderedfood/peppers_roastedpeppers.html

Comment: I LOVE this idea!  And yes, I don't have a bbq on my balcony.  But I do have a blow torch!

Comment: Who doesn't love a good excuse to break out the blow torch? I have fancy gadgets and am building a fancy kitchen. But my hardware propane torch is still one of my favourite kitchen tools. Nobody burn down your houses please.

Answer (score 8):

Roasting them under the broiler creates a nice even color and flavor.

Comment: You also don't have to roast them whole. Cut the peppers into large slices and roast that way -- that will enable you to roast evenly without turning. I generally broil them skin-side up on a broiler pan.

Comment: Do this. You'll get the char you're seeking, and roast the flesh as well (which you may or may not get with the blowtorch method).

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert, but I think you were on the right track. Just wait some time for the bell peppers to come loose from the burners.

Good luck

Comment: I am just concerned that there would be bits of pepper left on the burners, and the ones that my apartment has are not easy to clean.  :(

Comment: I guess you can just burn them off, anyway if you have an oven, try Cos Callis' method and use the broiler.